# Very weird performance behavior with pandas isin combined with boolean indexing with line_profiler

Tags: python, pandas, line-profiler

As seen here i am doing a isin() call which takes only 11126 to complete. Then i do a boolean indexing on that isin() but suddenly the time needed to complete that task is ~18x higher at 187088.

```
 2      11126.0   5563.0      0.5      randomness = ~dataframe.certificate_status.isin(
61         1          4.0      4.0      0.0          [
62                                                       "tamagotchi",
63                                                       "nintendo",
64                                                       "megaman",
65                                                       "mic_check",
66                                                       "onetwothree",
67                                                       "test",
68                                                       "else",
69                                                       "something",
70                                                   ]
71                                               )
72                                           
73         1     187088.0 187088.0      8.9      dataframe = dataframe.loc[randomness]
```

I actually expected boolean indexing to be faster than isin(). Can someone explain why i am getting the results seen here?

Comment: as an aside, why do you expect boolean to be faster than isin. I see it the other way, isin is likely executed by a binary search which is fast. the boolean indexing I'd suspect would be linear, and dependent on the size of the data. I have little knowledge on the implementation of boolean indexing, just an assumption

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example

Comment: But isn't boolean indeixing just taking a vector, thus one operation? Why does loc have to search at all? It knows the positions @sammywemmy

I'll provide a reproducable example tomorrow

Comment: I also forgot to add that i expected loc to be blazing fast, because i use the [True, False, ... ] Vector generated from randomness to select the columns that i want.